# How to print a list of all ascii characters with php?

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I'm traying to print ascii characters but when the index arrives to the extended characters they appears with the question mark �. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtmZb.jpg)

For example, if i do `echo chr(160);` i get `oA==` when its supposed to be an `á`
How can i get the correct value without change the header charset or file encoding?

Im doing the follow:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 255; $i++) { 
    echo chr($i) . " - ";
}
```

My file is encoded with utf-8. when i set the header with ISO-8859-1 appears good. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAQB2.jpg)

```
header("content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

I tried to print only one character. See what happen:
[image: 1- See the value of the variable and how to print in the browser.]

[image: 2- See the value of the variable and how to print in the browser.]
Why the variable get that strange value.

Comment: Are you sure your file encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I'm using sublime Text that show me that.

Comment: I can't see any problem glaringly wrong to me. But just a little hint, you cannot define headers after output.

Comment: I just tell you why the variable doesn get the value "á" instead of "4Q=="

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve my doubt using the fuction utf8_encode which translate an ISO-8859-1 word to UTF-8. :) Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php  

    for ($i=0; $i < 256; $i++) { 
        echo utf8_encode( chr($i) );
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not know why this answer has not received more upvotes. The only issue is that it should be `256` and not `255` or else you miss out on `ÿ`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus or just put <= 255

Comment: @Coja Pedantically, yes, that is an option. Functionally, you've just restated my comment. Thanks

Comment: @MonkeyZeus hahahahahhaha, sorry, had to mention it :)

Comment: @Coja Hah, no sweat . I've decided to edit OP's answer myself now that you reminded me about my comment. It's been crickets for 3 years now...

Comment: @MonkeyZeus There you go, something good happened from my mention :D

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way also,

```
<?php
 for ($i=0; $i < 255; $i++) { 
    //echo chr($i) . " - ";
    echo mb_convert_encoding('&#' . intval($i) . ';', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES')." - ";
 }
?>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You most convert the characters to UTF-8:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 255; $i++) {
    echo mb_convert_encoding (chr($i), 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1') . " - ";
}
```